# Showing nodes and edges per timestamp

Tags: graph, graph-visualization, gephi

I'm trying to make a dynamic graph from a directed edge list of 20,618 edges with 35 timestamps:

| Source | Target | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| node1 | node2 | 1 |
| node2 | node3 | 2 |
| … | … | … |

When I enable timeline it doesn't act like a dynamic graph (I should only see ~15% of nodes and edges at a single timestamp but all are present at all stages of the timeline). Importing "timestamp" as intervals, timestamps, integers, intlist, and biginterval list none work.

When I convert timestamp to a dynamic column I set interval start at 1 and interval end at 35. New column "timestamp_dynamic" is represented by horizontal lines that when I click show "<[1.0, 35.0, 1]>" (with 1 changing for timestamp that edge is at). I assume they represent start and end of interval and timestamp. Changing values to "<[1.0, 2.0, 1]>" had no effect. How do I make a dynamic graph from this directed edge list?